# PHP preg_split()

Tags: php, preg-split

I am trying to use preg_split as below:

```
$tarea = "13.3R4.2";
$keywords = preg_split("/[0-9]*.[0-9][a-zA-Z]/", $tarea);
print_r ($keywords);
```

I am unable to capture the array [0] value. Below is the output:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 4.2 )
```

I want to capture both the indexes of the array. I am not sure what mistake I am doing here. Kindly help!!

The output I expect is:

```
Array ( [0] => 13.3R[1] => 4.2 )
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: You must escape the `.` or it means *any single character* in this context.

Comment: Expected output:
    Array ( [0] => 13.3R[1] => 4.2 )

Comment: using `preg_match` is more easy.

Comment: or just explode on R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). It splits a string *on* the specified separator, meaning it's not designed to return the separator. You want to be using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to return matched substrings:

```
$tarea = "13.3R4.2";
preg_match_all("/[0-9]+\.[0-9][a-z]?/i", $tarea, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Note that `preg_split` can return the separator if  you use the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option.

Comment: Was not aware of that; I still think `preg_match_all()` is a more obvious function to use.

Comment: I think too, but in this case you need to describe the content on the right of the letter and use capture groups. (like michael pattern but with `preg_match`)

Answer (score 1):

Below code solved the issue:

```
$tarea = "13.3R4.2";
$keywords = preg_split('/(\d*\.\d\w?)/',$tarea, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE |     PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r ($keywords);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 13.3R [1] => 4.2 )
```

Thank you all for the great help!!!

Comment: If I were you, I will consider comments and other answers to find the most appropriate way.

Comment: if you absolutely want to use `preg_split`, you can do that: `preg_split('~(?<=[a-zA-Z])~', $tarea);`